# Exhaustive events and the law of total probability

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are exhaustive events with $Y$ and $Z$ being mutually exclusive. Can $Y$ and $Z$ be treated as a partition? Also, as a follow-up, can the law of total probability be applied to $X$ this way: $P(^cX) = P(^cX \cap Y) + P(^cX\cap Z)$, where $^cX$ is the complement of $X$?

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider P(X) = .4, P(Y) = .2, P(Z) = .2, with X,Y,Z disjoint and P(X) + P(Y) + P(Z) = 1 (exhaustive). Then Y and Z do not partition our probability space.

For the second part, since Y and Z do not partition our probability space, no, we cannot say that. If Y and Z did partition our probability space, then yes, we can say that.

Answer (score 1):

$Y$ and $Z$ are mutually exclusive, but may not be exhaustive on their own, so therefore they will not form a partition of $X\cup Y\cup Z$, *unless* $X\smallsetminus(Y\cup Z)$ is empty.

Still, $\{Y, Z, X\smallsetminus(Y\cup Z)\}$ would be a partition over that outcome space, and so therefore...

Comment: I see.. So suppose $X$ and $Y$ were independent. Could one use the above expansion to find $P(Z \cup ^cX)$? Or is there a better way to determine $P(Z \cup ^cX)$?

Comment: Yes, you can use it.   The expression turns out to be quite tidy.

Comment: Okay thank you!